# WPF Command Line

Tags: wpf, command-line, exit

I am trying to create a WPF application that takes command line arguments. If no arguments are given, the main window should pop up. In cases of some specific command line arguments, code should be run with no GUI and exit when finished. Any suggestions on how this should properly be done would be appreciated.

Answer (score 162, accepted):

First, find this attribute at the top of your App.xaml file and remove it:

```
StartupUri="Window1.xaml"
```

That means that the application won't automatically instantiate your main window and show it.

Next, override the OnStartup method in your App class to perform the logic:

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnStartup(e);

    if ( /* test command-line params */ )
    {
        /* do stuff without a GUI */
    }
    else
    {
        new Window1().ShowDialog();
    }
    this.Shutdown();
}
```

Comment: Can you interact with the console (Console.ReadLine/WriteLine) at that point?

Comment: Certainly you can call Console.WriteLine, but the output won't appear on the console from which you launched the app. I'm not sure what "Console" is in the context of a WPF application.

Comment: In order to write to the console in which the app was launched, you need to call AttachConsole(-1), Console.Writeline(message), and then FreeConsole() when you're done.

Comment: BEWARE: In Windows1.xaml, we cannot use App resources. They are not yet loaded: they are loaded in System.Windows.Application.DoStartup (internal method) and DoStartup is called just after OnStartup.

Answer (score 27):

To check for the existence of your argument - in Matt's solution use this for your test:

e.Args.Contains("MyTriggerArg")

Answer (score 7):

A combination of the above solutions, for .NET 4.0+ with output to the console:

```
[DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
public static extern bool AttachConsole(int processID);

protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnStartup(e);

    if (e.Args.Contains("--GUI"))
    {
        // Launch GUI and pass arguments in case you want to use them.
        new MainWindow(e).ShowDialog();
    }
    else
    {
        //Do command line stuff
        if (e.Args.Length > 0)
        {
            string parameter = e.Args[0].ToString();
            WriteToConsole(parameter);
        }
    }
    Shutdown();
}

public void WriteToConsole(string message)
{
    AttachConsole(-1);
    Console.WriteLine(message);
}
```

Alter the constructor in your MainWindow to accept arguments:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

And don't forget to remove:

```
StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below in `app.xaml.cs` file :

```
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    MainWindow WindowToDisplay = new MainWindow();

    if (e.Args.Length == 0)
    {
        WindowToDisplay.Show();
    }
    else
    {
        string FirstArgument = e.Args[0].ToString();
        string SecondArgument = e.Args[1].ToString();
        //your logic here
    }
}
```