# How to capture command line arguments in WPF application?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

How do I get the command line arguments in a Crystal Report WPF Application?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/426421/1048330

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Call [`Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood you right, how about this: [Processing Command Line Arguments Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa972153.aspx)?