# How to get opened file at startup?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012

I'm currently making a **Media Player in WPF and C#** (Visual Studio 2012), I've implemented all basics functions like opening video/music/image, it can be played or paused, the user can manage playlists, ...

Now when I want to use my application as the default player, I need to **open the selected file at startup** to launch the media. How to retrieve the file opened when I launch my application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file to open will be given to your program via command line arguments. Have a look for example here, it's a comprehensive discussion about retrieving/parsing the command line arguments for a c# program: [Best way to parse command line arguments in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491595/best-way-to-parse-command-line-arguments-in-c)
Or here: [WPF Command Line Arguments, a smart way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343381/wpf-command-line-arguments-a-smart-way)