# C# Application Parameters from Web Page

Tags: javascript, c#, web

I have an web page and a desktop app(C#). On a click in link in Web pages opens the c# application.

We need to send data from Web page to C# application, C# code should receive it.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
  <i>  function RunFile() {
    WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
    WshShell.Run("C:\hehe\ccslabsLogIn, 1, true");
    }</i>
</script>
<input type="button" value="Run Notepad" onclick="RunFile();"/>
```

Thanks for Help.

Comment: Hey, welcome to SO! Show us the code you've written so far. No one is going to write the code for you from scratch. This is a troubleshooting site, not free coding!

Answer (score 0):

```
WshShell.Run("C:\hehe\ccslabsLogIn <myString>, 1, true");
```

just replace `<myString>` with the argument you want to pass.

as for handling the argument:
[How do I pass command-line arguments to a WinForms application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179532/how-do-i-pass-command-line-arguments-to-a-winforms-application)

and for WPF:
[WPF Command Line Arguments, a smart way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343381/wpf-command-line-arguments-a-smart-way)