# Invoke WPF application from Winform Application with parameters

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

How to run/invoke a WPF application (.exe) from a Windows Forms ? I know it can be done like shown below:

```
 Process.Start(@"C:\ABC\WPF.exe");
```

But I want to send few parameters to the WPF Applications from the winform application. How to do it ?

Comment: `Process.Start()` has some overloads. [One of them](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Diagnostics_Process_Start_System_String_System_String_) allows to supply the arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer to complete code from [here](https://github.com/vkgpt11/StackOverFlowSuppot/tree/master/MixedDesktopApps)

You can pass arguments from your winform app like

`Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\repos\WpfApp.exe", "Args from WinForms"));`

and receive in WPF app like

```
public partial class App : Application
    {
        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnStartup(e);
            if (e.Args.Length > 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show($"You have passed:{e.Args.Length} arguments," +
                    $" value are {string.Join( ",",e.Args)}");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have 1 more doubt. The path of the wpf project exe cannot be hardcoded like this. We have a win form application [main application] and a wpf application. when running the winform application, at some point of time there is a need of invoking wpf application. at that time how we can speciy the path of the wpf application ?

Comment: place your WPF App binaries in a folder in same path of your WinForm App  and use relative path. "./WPFApp/Wpfapp.exe"

Comment: @VikasGupta `"./WPFApp/Wpfapp.exe"` will not work. If you include the wpf binaries in the winform project, this should work: `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"WPFApp\WpfApp.exe";`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same method with a few parameters. 
So in your case

```
var procStart = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\ABC\WPF.exe", params);
```